# Plot Projects : Notification aggregate stats result does not have relation with campaign, geofence and notification id

Tags: plot, notifications, statistics, project

Notification aggregate stats result does not have relation with campaign, geofence and notification id.

> API /notification/aggregated-stats

It will return:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "date": "2016-06-28",
      "viewed": 0,
      "sent": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

But it should be include `CampaignID`, `Geofence` and `NotificationID`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are separate API calls for aggregated stats for single campaigns or notifications;

```
/campaign/{campaignId}/aggregated-stats

/notification/{notificationId}/aggregated-stats
```

Unfortunately there is no API available as of yet for single Geofence statistics.

Documentation on the full statistics API can be found at https://admin.plotprojects.com/docs/api/v1/